# Entity Framework Core - Calling a Where linq method doesn't have relations

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm a newcomer to EF core, and I have a problem when I try to do the following. 
I have some business logic that filters coffees based on the price:

```cs
if(request.MoreThen != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(c =>
                    c.Prices
                    .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedAt)
                    .First()
                    .Price
                    >= request.MoreThen);
            }
```

And it works all and well. However, when I try to **extract** this functionality into a private method, I get that the `Prices` relation is null.

Now, I have several places I need to referance the latest price, here's the second if:

```cs
            if(request.MoreThen != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(c =>
                    c.Prices
                    .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedAt)
                    .First()
                    .Price
                    >= request.MoreThen);
            }
```

I find this not DRY at all, so I wanted to extract the fetching of the price into a private method like so:

```cs
private decimal GetPrice(Coffee model) 
{
  return model.Prices
     .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedAt)
     .First()
     .Price
}
```

However, now when I substitute the query:

```cs
   query = query.Where(c => GetPrice(c) <= request.LessThen)
```

I get a weird error, and in the debugger every field **is present** except for the **Included** ones. ( Do note that I called the `.Include` ) method.

The full code sample is included in my open source [Project on Github](https://github.com/dev-cyprium/coffeeterija/blob/b3f551d0d48fca3a41a731d10990d2cbfb9b2b4f/coffeterija.efcommands/Coffees/GetCoffee.cs#L37)

EDIT: I'm using Postgres as the Database engine, and code first approach

So my question is, why are the `.Prices` null even though I've included them at the start of the method?

Comment: EF Core translate expression trees into SQL expression. In your case, I suspect it doesn't know what to do with your `GetPrice` method. I'd even wager that you get a warning about the expression being evaluated client side.

Comment: Is there a way I can abstract this then, but avoiding my own function call? I'm looking for a way to keep things DRY.
I suspect I can `return Expression<Func<?, ?>` but I don't have enough experience to make that since I'm only been doing dot net core for the past few days

Comment: in your GetPrice(Coffee model) method, why use c.Prices instead of model.Prices? Is c a public list of Coffee objects?

Comment: My bad! That's a mistake in the question. Need to edit that.

Comment: It's very weird, because if I debug the callback the list is there, but if I pass it to a private method, It's null instead. It's like passing it at a wrong time or something. ( I even tried adding `ref` )

Comment: @ShadowBlade The line model.Prices `is null` but every other field is there. In the debugger I can clearly see the other properties values, only the relations (lists in this case ) aren't being passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to operate on the `Coffee` class itself, however you can create an extension method on `IQueryable<Coffee>`.

For example:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IQueryable<Coffee> GetPriceMoreThen(this IQueryable<Coffee> query, decimal moreThen)
    {
        return query.Where(c =>
                           c.Prices
                            .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedAt)
                            .First()
                            .Price >= moreThen);
    }
}
```

which then you can call as such

```
query = query.GetPriceMoreThen(request.MoreThen);
```

Disclaimer: I'm making some assumptions on your model here